# How to number posts in order displayed in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

all I'm trying to do is get the number of the order in which the post is being displayed in the wordpress loop. I'm not looking for post-ID. To give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do, I'll show you an example:

```
<div class="post" id="post-1>
    ...
</div>
<div class="post" id="post-2>
    ...
</div>
```

The reason being is I want to style posts by their given order in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before "The Loop" begins:

```
<?php $number = 1; ?>
```

Inside "The Loop" but after your HTML:

```
<?php $number++; ?>
```

Then anywhere in your HTML, you can output the post number by printing the value of `$number`.

```
<?php echo $number; ?>
```

Example in a WordPress theme file:

```
<?php $number = 1; ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post" id="post-<?php echo $number; ?>">
        ...
    </div>

    <?php $number++; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```